# Quick PHP syntax error

Tags: php

I have an error, I want to write:

```
public_path('upload\avatar\' . $variable);
```

But the last \ as if it was just a ' because there is a \ before, so it makes \'..
Any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to backslash escape the backslash itself, because otherwise it looks like it's trying to escape the quote:

```
public_path('upload\avatar\\' . $variable);
```

Comment: Note: Your accept ratio is quite low. Please mark answers as accepted if they properly address your issue, or users may be hesitant to help you in the future.